# implementation of asynchronous thread in c++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am unable to find a correct usage of asynchronous thread in c++11.The thing i want to do is i want to spwan threads and each thread will function simultaneously without waiting for each other like thread.join(),which makes other thread to wait until the current thread is done with.So,is there any library in c++ which makes threads to run parallely doing their work simultaneously without having to wait for the other to complete.Actually the thing i want is i want to run each threads sumultaneously, so that they don't wait for the other to complete and its functionality is executed simultaneously without having to wait for others to finish .
Thanks,
Kushal

EDIT:
EDIT:: i am posting the code below

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <csignal>
#include "paho_client.h"
using namespace std;
vector<string>    topic_container{"rpi2/temp","sense                          /bannana","sense/util","mqtt/temp","sense/temp","sense/pine","sense/fortis/udap"};
 vector<paho_client> publisher;
 vector<paho_client> subscriber;
 int finish_thread=1;
 void Onfinish(int signum){
 finish_thread=0;
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 signal(SIGINT, Onfinish);
 int topic_index;
 if(argc<3){
    cout<<"the format of starting commandline argument is"<<endl;              
    exit(1);
    }

    while(finish_thread!=0){
    //paho_client::get_library_handle();
    if(strcmp(argv[1],"create_publisher")){
        for(topic_index=0;topic_index<atoi(argv[2]);topic_index++){
            thread pub_th;
            pub_th = thread([ = ]() {
                paho_client client("publisher", "192.168.0.102", "9876",
                                   topic_container[topic_index].c_str());
                client.paho_connect_withpub();
              publisher.push_back(client);
            });
         pub_th.join();
        }
        vector<paho_client>::iterator it;
        int publisher_traverse=0;
        for(it=publisher.begin();it<publisher.end();publisher_traverse++){
           publisher[publisher_traverse].increment_count();
          publisher[publisher_traverse].get_count();
       }

   }
  }
 return 0;
}
```

After using async with future am getting the same behaviour as above please point me where am i going wrong

```
 #include <signal.h>
 #include <thread>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <cstring>
#include <csignal>
#include <future>
#include "paho_client.h"
using namespace std;
vector<string> topic_container{"rpi2/temp","sense/apple","sense/bannana","sense/util","mqtt/temp","sense/temp","sense/pine","sense/fortis/udap"};
vector<paho_client> publisher;
vector<paho_client> subscriber;
int finish_thread=1;
void Onfinish(int signum){
finish_thread=0;
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int accumulate_block_worker_ret(int topic_index) {
//int topic_index=0;
paho_client client("publisher", "192.168.0.102", "9876",
                   topic_container[topic_index].c_str());
client.paho_connect_withpub();
publisher.push_back(client);
client.increment_count();
return client.get_count();
 }


    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    signal(SIGINT, Onfinish);

    if(argc<3){
    cout<<"the format of starting commandline argument is . /paho_client_emulate <create_publisher><count of publisher client to spawn>"  <<endl;
    exit(1);
   }

     while(finish_thread!=0){
//   paho_client::get_library_handle();
     int topic_index;
      if(strcmp(argv[1],"create_publisher")){
     for(topic_index=0;topic_index<atoi(argv[2]);topic_index++){
    //  thread pub_th;
    // pub_th = thread([ = ]() {
       future<int> f =  async(std::launch::async,accumulate_block_worker_ret,topic_index);
    //      });
    //  pub_th.join();
        cout<<"the returned value from future is"<<f.get()<<endl;
       }

    vector<paho_client>::iterator it;
    int publisher_traverse=0;
    for(it=publisher.begin();it<=publisher.end();publisher_traverse++){
        cout<<"came here"<<endl;
        publisher[publisher_traverse].increment_count();
        publisher[publisher_traverse].get_count();
     }

     }
     }
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Threads *by definition* run in parallel. Calling `join` does not change that (except for the caller). `join` is used to wait for a thread to finish. But it doesn't somehow prevent other threads from running in parallel. You have either not expressed your question clearly or you have some fundamental misunderstanding of how threads work.

Comment: sorry i misinterpreted my question threads do run parallelly but but what i do want is i want threads to not wait for the other to complete .They should run their functionality simultaneously without having to wait .

Comment: Then don't call `join`. It's that simple. You don't have to do anything to not wait. You only have to do something (call `join`) if you do want to wait. So your thinking is all backwards.

Comment: if i dont call join .it gives active exception.I mean if i call detach on the threads it will not guarantee that i will get the outputs of all the thread.In other words i want all threads to run its  inner code and output its data

Comment: Then that is a different question. So your question makes no sense as currently worded. On one hand you don't want to wait for the threads but on the other hand you do want to wait for the threads. That's just utter confusion. Show your code, describe what you want it to do and describe what it is actually doing instead. Your question is currently an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Actually what i do want is i want to output each threads simultaneously without having to wait for the other to complete .

Comment: Show. your. code. The correct way to do that is to not call `join` in the child threads but do call `join` in the main thread. If you think you have done that and it still doesn't work then we can't help you unless you show the code.

Comment: Consider using [futures](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) with [async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) using  [async launch policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch). Then you'll only wait for the results and let the library/OS do the scheduling.

Comment: @kaylum mmm... I don't know about the " On one hand you don't want to wait for the threads but on the other hand you do want to wait for the threads". He's interested in launching the jobs and waiting for the results.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi thats exactly what i need in this special case i want to launch all the publisher clients first (as threads) and later publish messages from each threads

Comment: @KushalBhattacharya See my prev comment: use async to schedule your jobs and futures to wait for the answers. The linked pages have some examples too.

Comment: Actually i am running infinite while inside every instance of paho_client so the first thread is not completed even if i use future  that thread is run continously

Comment: If you never call join() it becomes very difficult to shut down your program safely, since the still-running threads will likely still be accessing the resources that you (or the runtime environment) is freeing.  Hence the crashes on shutdown in programs that don’t join() their threads before freeing resources.  (Note that there is often implicit resource-freeing code in the runtime that rubs after main() returns)

Answer (score 1):

> i want to launch all the publisher clients first (as threads) and
>   later publish messages from each threads

The `pub_th.join()` is misplaced inside the loop where the threads are started, thus waiting for the termination of each thread before starting the next one. To let the threads run in parallel, just move the `.join()` outside that loop. Of course to access the threads after the loop body, they have to be stored somewhere, e. g. in a `vector` - for this, change the first `for` loop to

```
        vector <thread> pub_threads;
        for (topic_index=0; topic_index<atoi(argv[2]); topic_index++)
        {
            pub_threads.push_back(thread([ = ]() { /* whatever */ }));
        }
```

and later when done:

```
        for (auto &th: pub_threads) th.join();
```

> Actually i am running infinite while inside every instance of
>   paho_client so the first thread is not completed …
>   that thread is run continously

Of course if never done, there's no point to `.join()`.